# Simple read file issue in python

Tags: python, file, input, io, readfile

Why does a call to this function results in this output in python:

```
['54044', '14108', '79294', '29649']
['']
['']
```

Function is called in this manner:

```
print read_file(FILENAME)
```

Code of function:

```
def read_file(filename):
"""
Reads in the file and returns a unsorted list of all the numbers in the file.
"""
file = open(filename)

# Why don't these 2 do the same thing?
print file.read().split('\r\n')
print file.read().split('\r\n')

numbers = file.read().split("\r\n")
file.close()

return numbers
```

As a sidenote, to get the numbers I need to split up the file using the escape sequences \r and \n. Is there any reasoning to the person using these two escape sequences in the file in succession, as opposed to just \n? (the file has a list of 1000 numbers that need to be arranged in a particular manner)

Comment: Is that exactly how your program looks? Because the indentation under `read_file` is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file, you get an object that remembers its current position in the file. So when you do `f.read()`, you reach the end: subsequent calls to `read()` will not return anything, because there is no more content.

You can reset your position by doing `f.seek(0)`, or by re-opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

Because `file.read` progresses while reading the file. You read whole file and never return back. (Assuming the indentation is actually ok.)

[Documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional numeric argument. **When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned;** it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and returned. **If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will return an empty string ("").**

Answer (score 1):

The file is being read sequentially, so the first call to file.read() reads from the beginning of the file. The second call attempts to read from where the previous one finished, which is the end of the file, so no content.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with files, it's generally more pythonic to use a `with` block as it handles closing the file automatically:

```
def read_file(filename):
    """
    Reads in the file and returns a unsorted list of all the numbers in the file.
    """
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        numbers = f.read().split('\r\n')

    return numbers
```